# How to format status code in JSON, application wide

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

For now I use, for example, `return Json(NotFound());` in each controller. I am looking for an application wide configuration.
**The JSON body must contains the status code.**

Comment: Calling `return Json(NotFound());` would return a HTTP 200, why would you want that?

Comment: You could write a class with a static method that returns your `Json(NotFound())` and call it from each controller?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, `return Json(NotFound());` gives `{"statusCode":404}` not HTTP 200

Comment: No, it returns HTTP 200 with the body `{"statusCode":404}`. That's tricking the client into thinking everything went OK when it didn't

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, sorry, I mean the body of the request… But if you have a suggestion to return the good status code with my json body.

Comment: When you're returning JSON it takes arguments in his constructor and converts it to JSON key value, the HTTP Status will be 200, the text inside your JSON will be "just" text, 404.

You basically have 2 options.  1. Make base class that every controller will inherit from it, and implement basic methods that returns specific values that you want.

2. Create class that contains static methods which returns the basic output you want, same concept as my first suggestion.

Comment: Sounds that there is no built in manner to get the good status code and the JSON body?

Comment: What JSON body? Returning `NotFound()` is an empty response body. You'll get a 404, but that's it. However, most of the `IActionResult` have an `ObjectResult` version. When you pass an object into the factory method, it will then serialize the object and return it as JSON by default (though that can be customized). In other words, `return NotFound(obj);` rather than `return Json(NotFound())`.

Comment: For application wide configuration, use filter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Chris Pratt. **JSON body must contains the status code**. The client gets the status like this.

Comment: The point is that that's on you. You can return whatever JSON you like, but it's not going to happen magically for you. Returning NotFound only affects the response status code, not the body. If you need the status code in the body as well, then you need to pass back and object with that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, In the header, not really, but theoretically, it should be the case, it would be better.

Comment: @aguafrommars, thanks, as there is no built in way, I find your suggestion very good as I could modify the status code as well. Could you post your comment as answer?

Comment: It actually wouldn't be better. The response content is your responsibility. If ASP.NET Core filled it, then you couldn't, which would make the framework unusable.

Comment: You should properly implement REST in your service instead of trying to attempt such hacks (You seem stuck in [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/392095)). The client should use the http code in the http response, not in some document embedded in it

Comment: @Tseng, no XY Problem. Sometime, you do not have control to some parts of a given system. You do what is asked, whatever hacks is needed. Moreover, aguafrommars's solution is perfect of my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For application wide configuration, use filter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1

IMHO you should return null in your controller's methods and create an ActionFilter checking for null result and returning `{"statusCode":404}`

To register the filter use something like :

```
services.AddMvc(configure =>
{                    
    configure.Filters.Add<MyActionFilter>();
})
```